# how do you change a database filter based on a link you click in django?

Tags: python, django

I would like to click on a link from my Django page and based on the link i clicked display a new database query filter from that name on the list

```
            <tr>
                <th>RootGroup List</th>

            </tr>

                {% for status in root %}
            <tr>
            <td><a href={{status.rootgroup }}> {{ status.rootgroup }} </a></td>
        #I WANT TO CLICK THE LINK AND DISPLAY A NEW DATABASE BASED ON THE NAME WITH A FILTER OF THE NAME
            </tr>

                {% endfor %}
```

---

```
def display(request):
    x = re.search('d.*','% url ''detail'' poll.id %')

    rootFilter = Viewroot.objects.filter(rootstatus__gt=0, type = 1, ("LINK NAME")).values('rootgroup').distinct() #RootGroup List
    #return render_to_response('status/index.html', { 'root' : rootFilter  },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    #return HttpResponse( x.group(0)),render_to_response('status/index.html', {'app' : appFilter})
    return HttpResponse("You displayed ", j )`
```

Comment: for example: i have <td><a href=Bowser> Bowser</a></td> and when i click it, it will send me to localhost:##/bowser and there i would like to display a database that filters only things with the bowser name on it, but it has to be dynamic and in django, no hardcore because i have over 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can make this work by using `named groups` in your `urls.py` patterns, e.g.:

```
(r'^links/(?P<value>\w+)/$', display)
```

Then, you can access saved part of url inside your view, like:

```
def display(request, value=None):
    print value
```

And, of course, you should use appropriate url in the template:

```
<td><a href="links/{{ status.rootgroup }}/"> {{ status.rootgroup }} </a></td>
```

Also see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).

Comment: thank you this helped with what i wanted to do, but i excluded the links because i am working with servers